# Docker: ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile

I am trying to copy all the files from a folder into a folder within a docker image as it's being built. Here is my error from my gitlab pipeline when it tries to build the docker image.

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:1.18.0-alpine
 ---> 8c1bfa967ebf
Step 2/3 : COPY conf/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../../src/ ()
 ---> ffbb72db6c26
Step 3/3 : COPY ../../src/ /var/www/html/public
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

[Here is the dockerfile + folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usWXD.png)

My gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: docker:stable

services:
- docker:18-dind
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375

php:

  before_script:
    - docker login gitlab.domain.com:5050 -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
  script:
    - docker build -t gitlab.domain.com:5050/project/php:7.2-fpm ./php-fpm
    - docker push gitlab.domain.com:5050/project/php:7.2-fpm

nginx:

  before_script:
    - docker login gitlab.domain.com:5050 -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
  script:
    - docker build -t gitlab.domain.com:5050/project/nginx:stable ./nginx
    - docker push gitlab.domain.com:5050/project/nginx:stable
```

Comment: It seems your path to src folder is not working as you want, can you try like this `COPY ../src/ /var/www/html/public`? Or maybe you can add an extra layer as `RUN ls ..` to see the content of the parent directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the [docker documention](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

> The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.

As an alternative, you can update the directory structure like this:

```
- code
  - nginx
  - php-fpm
  - src
  - Dockerfile
```

Then update the source path for `COPY` command in Dockerfile.

Updated Dockerfile:

```
FROM
RUN

COPY php-fpm/php-fpm.d/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY src/ /var/www/html/public/src/

WORKDIR
CMD
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I updated my question to provide the gitlab-ci file is it possible to set the context from here?

Answer (score 1):

`COPY` adds files from your Docker client’s current directory.

from https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

```
COPY obeys the following rules:

The <src> path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot COPY ../something /something, 
because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) 
to the docker daemon.

If <src> is a directory, the entire contents of the directory are copied, 
including filesystem metadata.
```

so please restructure the docker project structure and COPY the content inside the current directory structure.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I updated my question to provide the gitlab-ci file is it possible to set the context from here?